# Using Active Directory for Authorization in .Net

Tags: .net, active-directory

Beyond the simple code samples for doing basic AD functions using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, are there general guidelines or could somebody post their own on integrating .net with an application?  I have a standalone database of projects.

Projects can be assigned to a user.  Should I store the UserPrincipleName, the Distinguished name, the GUID, or the SID in the database?

Parts of a project are restricted to employees in a particular department.  Do I create a simple AD group for each department?  Should I favor some sort of local caching or multiple IsMemberOf calls?

How should I handle more granular permissions like CanDoSomething.  Should I nest more groups?

Comment: ObjectGUID is the immutable property across all those so that's what you want to go for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application and the users using it are all on the same LAN, I would definitely recommend using direct Windows Auth.

That is:

- for each group of users in your app (regular users, demo users, admins), create a Windows / AD Security groups - those can be administered and handled by any Windows/AD admin (no special tools / UI stuff needed)
- in your code, use the `IsInRole` method on the current `WindowsPrincipal` to figure out if that current user is in a particular role (or not)
- more granular permissions: that's entirely up to you; there are some "out of the box" solutions like AzMan, but none really seem to be used a lot - we mostly "roll our own" with some kind of a two- or three-layer approach (user - profile - permission) that is managed in the database and adminsitered within our apps

The name of an AD object could change - so I would not use that as my unique and stable reference. The GUID or the SID are both fixed and don't change - the GUID even more so (SID's can be merged under certain circumstances and thus might change - more for groups, but it's still possible)

Comment: Thank you.  For the most part I planned on creating a bunch of groups but azman looks promising.